# Have PS script wait for NotifiyIcon click, then display messagebox and exit

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a situation where I need a scheduled task to run a script, check for certain certificates to be near expiring, and then notify the user. I have chosen to use a Windows Forms NotifyIcon object, since I can then pop up a nice little balloon that looks integrated into the OS. I want it to display a MsgBox when the user clicks on the icon (well, I want it to do it when they click on the icon, or balloon, but for now I'll settle on the icon).

The problem is that I can't get the script to wait for the user to click the icon, or if I setup a loop to make the script wait I can't seem to get the script to exit the loop when the user does click the icon. If the script simply exits without waiting the icon disappears, taking the balloon with it, so the user sees an icon and balloon flash on their screen and its gone before they can read it or interact with it. Here's a simplified version that exhibits the issue (you will need to change the icon path to a valid .ico file on your system).

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")|Out-Null

Function Show-MsgBox ($Text,$Title="",[Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]$Button = "OK",[Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]$Icon="Information"){
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Text", "$Title", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::$Button, $Icon) | ?{(!($_ -eq "OK"))}
}

#Create Notification Icon
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Click Me!"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "I'm a title"
$objNotifyIcon.Text = "Click Me!"
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\temp\vsmartcard.ico"

$NotDone = $true
$objNotifyIcon.add_click({Show-MsgBox -text "User Clicked Icon"; $Global:NotDone = $false})
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $true
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
While($NotDone){
    "`$NotDone = $NotDone`nSleeping for 3 seconds"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}

$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $False
$objNotifyIcon.Dispose()
```

Strangely this works as expected if I dot source it, but not if I just run the script.

I have tried registering events instead of using the `add_click` method and using the `Wait-Event` cmdlet, but it never registers that an event happens and it either sits there forever waiting for an event, of if I include a timeout it waits for that to expire and then completes the script and exits (in which case the user may never see my notification if they don't notice it in the 15 seconds for the timeout). The code that i tried with that is as follows (modified version of code I found in an SO answer by Keith Hill from years ago):

```
Register-ObjectEvent $objNotifyIcon BalloonTipClicked -SourceIdentifier event_BalloonTipClicked -Action {
    Show-MsgBox -Text $Text -Title $Title
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $event.SourceIdentifier -Force
    Remove-Job $event.SourceIdentifier -Force
    $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $False
}
Register-ObjectEvent $objNotifyIcon Click -SourceIdentifier event_Click -Action {
    Show-MsgBox -Text $Text -Title $Title
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $event.SourceIdentifier -Force
    Remove-Job $event.SourceIdentifier -Force
    $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $False
}

$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
wait-event
```

I tried including `Break` and `Exit` in the `Click` event scriptblock, but they just threw errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($Global:NotDone) { ... }
```

That way it refers to the same variable already being referenced in the event.

---

#### Stuff that turned out not to be relevant:

The issue is that there is nothing waiting for the event, as you've surmised. But trying to add the loop won't work because you only have one thread and now it's stuck sleeping and looping.

You probably need to use events for this, and then you need to be waiting on the event, not just sleeping.

I found [a good example of this on powershell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/16893.aspx):

```
param 
( 
    $msg = "For the latest updates check our intranet website. Please click in the balloon.", 
    $title = "News", 
    $icon = "None", 
    $timeout=1 
) 

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | out-null 

$Balloon = new-object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon  
$Balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information 
$Balloon.Visible = $true; 
$Balloon.ShowBalloonTip($timeout, $title, $msg, $icon); 

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
Register-ObjectEvent $Balloon BalloonTipClicked -sourceIdentifier click_event -Action { 

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.navigate2("https://intranet.mydomain.com") 
$ie.visible = $true 

} | Out-Null 

Wait-Event -timeout 15 -sourceIdentifier click_event > $null 
Remove-Event click_event -ea SilentlyContinue 
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$Balloon.Dispose()
```

It's `Wait-Event` here that's doing the proper waiting.

You said you had problems with this approach. Could you edit that code into the question too?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned (and will update my question) that I have tried `Wait-Event`. The script looping is not the issue, as it does show the msgbox when I click the icon with my script, but the loop never ends. `Wait-Event` with registered events does the same thing. In the case of the script you provided it waits 15 seconds for the user to click, and then continues on, and the notification icon goes away, so the user could completely miss it and never know it was ever there. If you exclude the timeout it waits forever and never registers that an event happened.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician what if you use `$Global:NotDone` in the `while` loop (to make sure it's the same variable referenced in the event)?

Comment: I have not! Well, I had not, but now I have, and now I feel foolish because that fixed it for me. Always something so simple. Thank you very much! Add that to your answer and I'll gladly mark it as accepted.